# Is it possible to avoid to `git push` a branch to REMOTES - ORIGIN if any commits was done?

Tags: git, push, githooks, git-push

I would need a hook that checks the `git push` operation.

If a brand new branch is created and it is identical to master, I would like a hook that prevent to push it to the remote origin.
Once the first commit to this branch is done, then the push to origin becomes possible.

Basically I want to avoid this situation

```
$ (master) git checkout -b ticket-abc master

$ (ticket-abc) git push origin ticket-abc
```

I would like to block this second line if there are no commits related to this new branch. Is there a way to manage this with git hooks?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean push the branch to origin? Do you mean merge?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: What effect do you want to avoid? The operation you describe has no effect since the new ref is the same as the old one. Nothing will be modified on remote and output locally "Everything up-to-date".

Comment: well, a new branch is pushed to origin with the name `ticket-abc` in remotes. I need to avoid to push branches on remotes - origin that are identical to master, so before any done commits.

Comment: OK, so you don't want new branch created if they don't bring any new commits. But I still don't get the point... is it a situation so frequent that it clutters your remote? Aren't these new branches eventually updated with commits? Don't you have a recurring cleaning routine for branches? Sorry for all the questions :-)

Comment: No worries, it is a good practice to make questions :) at the moment we have some issues between bitbucket and jenkins. bitbucket and jenkins misalign when this scenario happens. I know this is a hook and the problem should be solved somewhere else. I just would like that, until main issue is not fixed, that this bitbucket-jenkins misalignment occurs no more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook `pre-push` can be adopted.

```
#!/bin/bash

master_sha=$(git rev-parse refs/heads/master)
while read local_ref local_sha remote_ref remote_sha;do
    if [[ "${local_sha}" = "${master_sha}" ]];then
        echo error: ${local_ref} points at the same commit with master
        echo error: push failed
        exit 1
    fi        
done
exit 0
```

But I'm a bit concerned by the stability of the local `master`. If it happens to be updated by accident, the hook can't detect its change and thus can't fail the push as expected.

Comment: Can you define better "to be updated by accident" ? what do you mean?

Comment: `foo` is created from `master`, and `master` is updated by `git pull`, `git commit`, or other commands that move `master` to a new commit before `foo` is pushed.

Comment: I've to say, in my scenario, the push was done, so the hook didn't work

Comment: @axel Is the hook invoked? What are the values of `${local_sha}` and `${master_sha}`?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the [`update`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#update) server-side hook:

> The hook executes once for each ref to be updated, and takes three parameters:
>
> - the name of the ref being updated,
> - the old object name stored in the ref,
> - and the new object name to be stored in the ref.

Then I would do something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

refname="$1"
oldrev="$2"
newrev="$3"

master=$(git rev-parse refs/heads/master)

if [ "$newrev" = "$master" ]; then
    echo "Rejected: $refname has no new commits compared to master" >&2
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Here we're simply comparing the SHA-1 of the commit (`newrev`) referenced by the branch being pushed (`refname`) to the SHA-1 of the commit referenced by `master`. If they're equal, we exit with an error code, thereby preventing *that particular branch* from being created on the server.

From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#update):

> Just before updating the ref on the remote repository, the update hook
>   is invoked. Its exit status determines the success or failure of the
>   ref update.

Comment: I've to say, in my scenario, the push was done, so the hook didn't work

Comment: This hook runs on the server so, naturally, it reacts to a `push` operation being done. However, it will stop the branch from being _created_ on the remote.